# A way to get all objects instances from JVM memory

Tags: java, memory, jvm

Is there a way to get all objects instances from JVM memory and print its' toString() representation in file?

I need to do a shot of all my app's objects instances in moment of error.

I think dump is not what I looking for because it doesn't give me precise information about what instances were contained in memory at the moment, only statictics information.

Comment: What problem will this solve for you?

Comment: Are you asking how to take a heap dump?

Comment: @NomadMaker I need to log information about system usage in moment of error by remote user, so I need information similar to information providing by IDE in debug mode.

Comment: @andy-turner Does heap dump provide information about instances of objects - their global variables and local variables from method at the moment of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is essentially called heap dump.

Heapdump is a snapshot of JVM memory in a given time, it contains info about all the objects.

To capture it you can do

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.bin <pid>
```

- pid: id of the Java process

There are several tools that can analyze the file outputted. Good change is that your IDE can do it, that way you can view it in familiar interface.

More here
https://dzone.com/articles/java-heap-dump-analyzer-1

To programatically trigger hepdump you can do something like this

```
public class HeapDumper {
    
    private static final String HOTSPOT_BEAN_NAME =
        "com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic";
    private static volatile HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean hotspotMBean;

    static void dumpHeap(String fileName, boolean live) {
        initHotspotMBean();
        try {
            hotspotMBean.dumpHeap(fileName, live);
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            throw re;
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exp);
        }
    }

    private static void initHotspotMBean() {
        if (hotspotMBean == null) {
            synchronized (HeapDumper.class) {
                if (hotspotMBean == null) {
                    hotspotMBean = getHotspotMBean();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean getHotspotMBean() {
        try {
            MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
            HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean bean =
                ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(server,
                                                         HOTSPOT_BEAN_NAME, HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class);
            return bean;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            throw re;
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exp);
        }
    }
}
```

Triggering it like this

```
String fileName = "heap.bin";
boolean live = true; // only reachable object - true, all objects - false
dumpHeap(fileName, live);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can I access JMAP through Java code?

Comment: Added the code explaining how to trigger it manually. What is your use case? In my 10 years of programming I only needed this once. Maybe you are overdoing something.

Comment: Nice answer! I would also like to know the use cases.

Comment: Thank you again. I develop a logger module for a Java application. Application is a parser with some other functionalities. It can produce variety of errors, so there is a need to log information about it, including heap dump at the moment of error. Heap dump that includes information about object instances can provide useful information about what entity was processing at the error moment. Are there some better practices for this use case?

Comment: Heapdumping is not a cheap or quick operation. So consider how offen are the errors can lead to more issues.